# Exponential matrix, run during infinit amount of time

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, expression-manipulation, run

Context: I want to apply an exponential matrix on a vector. The size of the matrix (which then I apply the MatrixExp on) is size of 50x50, and not diagonal. For reason I don't know, Mathematica take a infinit  time (I stoped after 1hour) for computing it.

here is the detail:

My vector is a Kronecker product between two states:

```
 vecfin = KroneckerProduct[m, pointfin] // Flatten;
```

were the two states are: `m = {\[Alpha], \[Beta]};`and `pointfin = KroneckerProduct[pointx, pointz];`  with `pointx =pointz= {0, 0, 1, 0, 0};`

Then the exponential matrix is

```
 `explus = MatrixExp[
    I*(KroneckerProduct[sigmax, pplus, id5] + 
       KroneckerProduct[sigmaz, id5, pplus])] // FullSimplify;`
```

where `sigmax = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};` and
`sigmaz = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}};` and

```
`pplus = {{0, -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], -(1/5) I Sqrt[
     2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi]}, {1/5 I Sqrt[
     2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 0, -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], -(1/5) I Sqrt[
     2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi]}, {-(1/5) I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    0, -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi]}, {1/5 I Sqrt[
     2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    0, -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi]}, {-(1/5) I Sqrt[
     2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], -(1/5) I Sqrt[
     2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 1/5 I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 0}};`
```

pplus is: [image: pplus expression] (what i wrote above, it's 5x5 matrix)

Question:
Mathematica run for an infinit amount of time, just for computing "explus". I would know if there is a way to make this calculation? I feel that the closer the matrix is diagonal the easiest it is for mathematica to do the MatrixExp; so I tried to diagonalize the matrix inside, but again, it run for infinit time...

At the end I want to compute, `exmoins.KroneckerProduct[U,id5,id5].explus.vecfin`

where U = Table[Subscript[u, i, j], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}]; (a 2x2 generic matric)

```
`id5 = IdentityMatrix[5];`   (identity matrix 5x5)
```

and

```
`exmoins = MatrixExp[
    -I*(KroneckerProduct[sigmax, pplus, id5] + 
       KroneckerProduct[sigmaz, id5, pplus])] // FullSimplify;` (same as explus but with "-" sign before the i)
```

Thank you for any help

PS: Here is the Mathematica code you can copy-paste

```
In[15]:= pointx = pointz = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
m = {\[Alpha], \[Beta]};
pointfin = KroneckerProduct[pointx, pointz];
id5 = IdentityMatrix[5];

sigmax = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
sigmaz = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}};

In[4]:= vecfin = KroneckerProduct[m, pointfin] // Flatten;

In[11]:= 
pplus = {{0, -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], -(1/5) I Sqrt[
      2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi]}, {1/5 I Sqrt[
      2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 0, -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], -(1/5) I Sqrt[
      2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi]}, {-(1/5) I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    0, -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi]}, {1/5 I Sqrt[
      2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    0, -(1/5) I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi]}, {-(1/5) I Sqrt[
      2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 
    1/5 I Sqrt[2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], -(1/5) I Sqrt[
      2 - 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 1/5 I Sqrt[2 + 2/Sqrt[5]] \[Pi], 0}};



(* I want to compute 'explus' this under; it take an infinit amount \
of time for me *)
explus = MatrixExp[
    I*(KroneckerProduct[sigmax, pplus, id5] + 
       KroneckerProduct[sigmaz, id5, pplus])] // FullSimplify;
exmoins = 
  MatrixExp[-I*(KroneckerProduct[sigmax, pplus, id5] + 
       KroneckerProduct[sigmaz, id5, pplus])] // FullSimplify;

Out[21]= $Aborted

Out[22]= $Aborted

In[23]:= U = Table[Subscript[u, i, j], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}];


(* Final goal is to compute; same take infinite time *)

final = exmoins.KroneckerProduct[U, id5, id5].explus.vecfin // 
  Simplify
```

Comment: You did not define `pointz`

Comment: Could do it using approximate numerical values.

Comment: sorry pointz=pointx={0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
Yes numerically it work, but I would keep the algebraic form; thats why Mathematica have pain ...

Comment: Can you please provide the complete code that could just be copy-pasted into Mathematica? Thks.

Comment: Yes I edit my post and add the mathematica code you can copy-paste on Mathematica at the end. Thanks

Comment: Change it to `MatrixExp[N[...]]` and get rid of the `FullSimplify` and `Simplify` and it works instantly. This matrix is too complex to keep it all in algebraic form.

Comment: Yes, I know with numerical approximation it work well. But I would keep it algebraic ... do you think it is impossible at all ?